# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-template

html

```
 <div class="py-4" *ngFor="let data of Question; let i = index">
   {{data | json}}
  </div>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
this.showQuestion();
}

Question: any [];
showQuestion() {
const Entity = new TaskViewEntity(someParameter, 'QuestionDetails');
this.serviceParameter.TaskApi(Entity.requestFormat).subscribe(res => {
  if (res['result'].questionDetails !== undefined) {
    const arr = res['result'].questionDetails.questions;
    this.Question = arr.map(item => {
      return {
        'counter': 1,
        'answer': item.answer,
        'approveFlag': item.approveFlag,
        'options': item.options,
        'question': item.question,
        'questionId': item.questionId,
        'questionType': item.questionType,
        'subQuestion': item.subQuestion
      };
    });
  }
});}
```

service.ts

```
public TaskApi = (data) => {
   const url = 'URL';
   return this.http.post(url, data);
}
```

Json

```
 "questions": [
      {
         "questionId": 44,
         "question": "abc",
         "questionType": "checkbox",
      },
      {
         "questionId": 44,
         "question": "abc",
         "questionType": "checkbox",
       },
       {
          "questionId": 44,
          "question": "abc",
          "questionType": "checkbox",
       },
   ]
```

After using console.log(this.Question), i get this result

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {counter: 1, answer: "", approveFlag: true, options: {…}, question: "Please confirm the address of the property is", …}
1: {counter: 1, answer: "", approveFlag: true, options: {…}, question: "Please confirm the name of the seller?", …}
2: {counter: 1, answer: "", approveFlag: true, options: {…}, question: "Please confirm the number of sellers/partners?", …}
```

The above mentioned code not working it shows the error in my console which is : Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. Angular.  I am not able to access questions.

Comment: ngFor works over an array. Check if Question is an arrya

Comment: question is an array.

Comment: It is an array like this => question: [{...}, {...}, {...}]

Comment: post the JSON to check

Comment: I have posted my json after editing my question. Please check

Comment: this is what this.Question shows?

Comment: Yes it does. In component.ts, when i used console.log(this.Question), I am getting the result. but i am unable to see the result in html

Comment: Where does showQuestion get called. Can you show full html?

Comment: showQuestion() gets called in ngOnInit. During the time of page load

Comment: Can you please create a https://stackblitz.com/ reproducing the issue?

Comment: Can you try this: Change the html to so that it passes the question object back to your component 
`<div class="py-4" data-test="logquestion(Question);">
  {{data | json}}
 </div>`
then in there 
  `logquestion(obj){
    console.log(obj);
  }`
and see if it's the same as the log you posted in your question?
I can only imagine it's something to do with your subscription and the object going to your html isn't what we expect it is.

Comment: Can you show me, where are you consoling the Question ? And also try `if(typeof this.Question == 'object') this.Question = []` after the mapping function

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not initialised the array questions in the first place , you are initialising it in subscribe , so until then it is uninitialised , can you try doing : 
`Question: any[] = [];`